# Combining rows and columns returned by kusto query into a single json key value object pair in javascript and applying pagination

Tags: node.js, azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

Hi I have some data in azure log analytics workspace, and have a requirement where we need to display the data retrieved from azure to my UI. Below is the query that i tried

```
"<tablename> | take 2"
```

And the result i received is

```
{
    "tables": [
      {
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        "columns": [
          {
            "name": "TenantId",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "TimeGenerated",
            "type": "datetime"
          },
          {
            "name": "Message",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "SeverityLevel",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "Properties",
            "type": "dynamic"
          }
        ],
        "rows": [
          [
            "242d7831-a5b0-4f0d-8324-acf22f51a9aa",
            "2023-06-07T16:11:35.834Z",
            "In Hanlder/getRolesDetailByRolename",
            1,
            "{\"service_name\":\"tenant-service\",\"environment\":\"dev\"}"
          
          ],
            [
            "242d7831-a5b0-4f0d-8324-acf22f51a9aa",
            "2023-06-07T16:15:40.834Z",
            "In Hanlder",
            1,
            "{\"service_name\":\"language-service\",\"environment\":\"dev\"}"
          
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

My requirement here is to performed pagination and send the data result as below to my UI

```
{
  "columns": [
    {
      "name": "TenantId",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "TimeGenerated",
      "type": "datetime"
    },
    {
      "name": "Message",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "SeverityLevel",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "Properties",
      "type": "dynamic"
    }
  ],
  "docs": [
    {
      "TenantId": "242d7831-a5b0-4f0d-8324-acf22f51a9aa",
      "TimeGenerated": "2023-06-07T16:11:35.834Z",
      "Message": "In Hanlder/getRolesDetailByRolename",
      "SeverityLevel": 1,
      "Properties": "{\"service_name\":\"tenant-service\",\"environment\":\"dev\"}"
    },
    {
      "TenantId": "242d7831-a5b0-4f0d-8324-acf22f51a9aa",
      "TimeGenerated": "2023-06-07T16:15:40.834Z",
      "Message": "In Hanlder",
      "SeverityLevel": 1,
      "Properties": "{\"service_name\":\"language-service\",\"environment\":\"dev\"}"
    }
  ],
  "totalDocs": 122,
  "limit": 10,
  "totalPages": 13,
  "page": 1,
  "pagingCounter": 1,
  "hasPrevPage": false,
  "hasNextPage": true,
  "prevPage": null,
  "nextPage": 2
}
```

I came across some thing called [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/stored-query-results](https://stackoverflow.com) ,But i am stuck as how to achieve it. Kindly guide as how to proceed further